# Добавить два элемента в массив

Tags: массивы, php

Все привет! Сразу извиняюсь, если вопрос детский..

Вот мой код:

```
$ar[]['date'] = $date;
$ar[]['text'] = $text;
```

И на выходе получается вот что:

```
$data = array(
    0 => array(
        'date' => '05.04.2013'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'text' => 'текст блаблабла'
    )
);
```

А надо так:

```
$data = array(
    0 => array(
        'date' => '05.04.2013'
        'text' => 'текст блаблабла'
    ),
);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array_push($data, array(
'date' => $date,
'text' => $text));
```

или

```
$data[] = array(
    'date' => $date,
    'text' => $text);
```

Comment: Спасибо!) Кстати а почему вы используете array_push, если работает просто присваивание?

Comment: а нет, просто не работает. Ладно, спасибо большое еще раз :)

Comment: ответ дополнил. Можно и просто присваивание, но есть же функция. На мой взгляд, если есть функция, которая выполняет эту работу, ее нужно использовать.